# Git-status, partial folder report

Tags: git, git-status

Is there a way to tell `git-status` to ignore the contents of specific folders when invoked from outside of these folders?

I would like to see the changes I made in these folders only when I enter them and call `git-status`. If possible I would like to have the same behavior but only for un-tracked files.

Example:

```
$ git init foo
$ cd foo
$ mkdir bar
$ git add bar

foo$ touch bar/README
foo$ git status ----> Empty
foo$ cd bar
foo/bar$ git status -----> README is un-tracked
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to take a look at submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: I don't use submodules as I want to have a single repository. Actually I am using `git-subtree` but I wish to avoid adding tons of generated temporaries to .gitignore files.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Git does not track empty directories at all. It is not likely to be reconsidered, too. But take a look at `git status -u` and accompanying configuration options.

Comment: What do you mean by empty? I don't think I mentioned any empty folders. `git status -u` doesn't do exactly that. thanks.

Comment: pipe the output through `grep`, filtering out things that start with `../`, and make an alias of this command -- call it `git substatus`

Comment: Thanks. I'll make another one to filter specific folders I wish to ignore.